# NextJs redirect based on Regex

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using Next.js and I am trying to redirect to a given path base on some regex conditions and cookie.

The goal is to redirect to `/foo/bar` when the source does not have the key `bar` and have a given cookie.

I have tried several different ways with `next.config.js` and none works.

Right now I have the following

```js
async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/(^(?:(?!bar).)*$)',
        has: [{
          type: 'cookie',
          key: 'utm_source',
          value: 'bar',

        }],
        destination: '/foo/bar',
        permanent: true
      }
    ]
  }
```

The documentation is quite vague.

Comment: have you checked this out ? https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/15712

Comment: I never gave it the attention i gave now. Yes it solves the problem, but it's too verbose. I would like to specify only a word that should not be in the source. I dont't care about the path. But thank you, worst case scenario i have this.

Comment: You can for sure, but i think (hope) there is another answer.

Answer (score 8):

I also had a regex issue and was digging deep into next.js source code and did a little debugging. What I found is that unfortunately nobody tells you that next.js wraps your regex inside `/^(?:\/(` your regex `))$/i`

Actually, the first part (`\/`) might depend on your source property.
But if you remove everything apart from the actual "word regex" it should work:

```
source: '/(?!bar)',
```

(Check out `regexp.source` in `getPathMatch()` in node_modules\next\dist\shared\lib\router\utils\path-match.js)

Answer (score 0):

Next.js started using the [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp) library for matching the routes. The project's README has more examples and a link to the testing tool: http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).