# Forward pages not matching a regexp to another backend in NextJS

Tags: regex, next.js, url-routing

I want to integrate a NextJS app with a Laravel application.

The [NextJS app](https://github.com/zbycz/osmapp) is responsible for the routes

```
/
/node/123456789
/way/123456789
/relation/123456789
/install
```

Where 123456789 any numbers.

The Laravel application should be responsible for all other URLs.

The all-page-routing of the NextJS app looks like this:

```
  const [osmtype, osmid] = all;
  const shortId =
    osmtype && osmtype.match(/^node|way|relation$/)
      ? osmtype.substr(0, 1) + osmid
      : id;

  if (!shortId) {
    return notFound();
  }
```

I am trying to do this with a rewrite in next.config.js

Currently I have negative lookahead regexp like this:

```
  rewrites: () => {
    return [
        {
          source: '/((?!node|way|relation|install):path*)',
          destination: `http://pages.example.com/:path*`,
        }
      ]
  }
```

But this would not match and call the 404 page of the NextJS app.

I also tried

```
source: '/((?!node|way|relation|install)):path*',
```

Here I got a bit closer.

Calling something like `http://nextjsapp.example.com/bar`

Would lead to a `GET /r` in the Apache access log of pages.example.com - so somehow :path* only was catching the last letter.

How can I make it match the full path and pass it to the Laravel backend?

Additionally I tried the fallback rewrite, but this does not seem to work due to the nature of the routing in the NextJs app - I still would get the 404 error.

Comment: This might help explain the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69518118/nextjs-redirect-based-on-regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*` was too much - also I don't know where the backticks came from in `destionation`. This works:

```
source: '/((?!node|way|relation|install):path)',
destination: 'http://pages.example.com/:path',
```

EDIT: If this should also work for subpaths, use

```
source: '/((?!node|way|relation|install)):path(.*)',
destination: 'http://pages.example.com/:path',
```